# Deleting HTML tables rows

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

I know there are like thousands of answers on Stack Overflow about this specific topic, but I have been reading them for 3 days and nights already trying to apply solutions to my code with no success.

The problem is that `addRow` works fine, but `DeleteRow` doesn't work at all.

Here is my HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="add" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" /> 
<input type="button" value="delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/> 
<p></p>
</p>
</table>
<table id="dataTable" class="cv" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" style="width:100%" placeholder="ievadiet valodu">
    </td>
    <td>
      <select id="BX_gender" name="BX_gender" required="required">
        <option>dzimtā valoda</option>
        <option>teicami</option>
        <option>labi</option>
        <option>viduvēji</option>
        <option>pamatzināšanas</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select id="BX_gender" name="BX_gender" required="required">
        <option>teicami</option>
        <option>labi</option>
        <option>viduvēji</option>
        <option>pamatzināšanas</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select id="BX_gender" name="BX_gender" required="required">
        <option>teicami</option>
        <option>labi</option>
        <option>viduvēji</option>
        <option>pamatzināšanas</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="clear"></div>
</fieldset>
```

javascript:

```
function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    if (rowCount < 5) {
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
        }
    } else {
        alert("Maksimālais ierakstu skaits ir 7.");
    }
}

function DeleteRow(o) {
    //no clue what to put here?
    var p = o.parentNode.parentNode;
    p.parentNode.removeChild(p);
}
```

Here is a fiddle with code working (only the `addRow` function): http://jsfiddle.net/7AeDQ/690/

Comment: That `DeleteRow()` function is written as if every row has its own delete button, but you have one delete button outside the table. Which row should the lone delete button delete? Think through just what the `this` is in `onclick="deleteRow(this)"`...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to delete the last row, you can use something like this

```
function deleteRow() {
     var table = document.getElementById("dataTable");
    var tbody = table.tBodies[0];
         tbody.removeChild(tbody.lastChild);
    }
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7AeDQ/696/)

Using something like this, you don't need to traverse the DOM using parentNode.parentNode...

Comment: why is this not deleting for the first time alone?!

Comment: thanks for putting your effort in this, pollirrata. your fiddle works, but i did include your solution in my script, row deleting doesnt work. What could be the reason? Some html - javascript connection problem on my machine?

Comment: @user3043888 please ensure that you're calling the function ´deleteRow´ when clicking the button..